# How to find the maximum for each type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this

| fruit | cost |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 5 |
| apple | 6 |
| banana | 8 |
| pear | 3 |
| banana | 9 |
| pear | 7 |

and i want the maximum cost of each type of fruit like

| fruit | cost |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 6 |
| banana | 8 |
| pear | 7 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group by` is your friend to find the maximum in each group of records.

```sql
select fruit, max(cost) as cost
  from _table
 group by fruit;
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, i have another case where there are two more columns (country, weight) and i want to add them as well what do i do? The method doesn't seem to work for more columns.

Comment: Maybe `select fruit, country, max(cost) as cost, max(weight) as weight from _table group by fruit, country;`